# Why is my array being reset to 0 after each loop?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to make a snake game but I run into a few problems. I have this thread which contains the game loop but it doesn't seem to work. This is a simple form of my loop, I simplified it because it didn't work at first but it doesn't still. What happens is that my `state` variable gets reset to 0 after the first loop and I really have no clue why. I tries so many ways to fix it but I can't seem to find the problem.

Oh yeah, also don't look at the sloppy start of my run method, I am trying to fix things and it gets rather ugly.

```
public void run() {
    alive = true;
    keyPressed = 2; // Right 
    keyPressedBefore = 2;
    field = Gui.getPanelArray();
    state = new int[20][20];
    newstate = new int[20][20];
    previous = new int[20][20];
    coordw = new int[20*20];
    coordh = new int[20*20];
    length = 2;
    width = height = 20;

    for (int w = 0; w < 20; w++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < 20; h++) {
            state[w][h] = 0;
        }
    }
    state[0][0] = 1;
    render(state,field);
    previous = state;
    newstate = state;

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    loop();
}

private void loop() {
    while (alive) {
        for (int w = 0; w < 20; w++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < 20; h++) {
                newstate[w][h] = 0;
            }
        }

        if (keyPressed == 0) {
            for (int w = 0; w < 20; w++) {
                for (int h = 0; h < 20; h++) {
                    if (state[w][h] == 1) {
                        newstate[w][h-1] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (keyPressed == 1) {
            for (int w = 0; w < 20; w++) {
                for (int h = 0; h < 20; h++) {
                    if (state[w][h] == 1) {
                        newstate[w-1][h] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (keyPressed == 2) {               
            for (int w = 0; w < 20; w++) {
                for (int h = 0; h < 20; h++) {
                    if (state[w][h] == 1) {
                        newstate[w][h+1] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (keyPressed == 3) {
            for (int w = 0; w < 20; w++) {
                for (int h = 0; h < 20; h++) {
                    if (state[w][h] == 1) {
                        newstate[w+1][h] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        render(newstate, field);
        state = newstate;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //keyPressedBefore = keyPressed;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first section of your loop explicitly sets the array to zero. Comment it out like

```
while (alive) {
    // for (int w = 0; w < 20; w++) {
    //    for (int h = 0; h < 20; h++) {
    //        newstate[w][h] = 0;
    //    }
    // }
```

Also, don't just assign the reference here

```
// state = newstate;
state = Arrays.copyOf(newstate, newstate.length);
```

Comment: That sets `newstate` to 0, I am talking about `state`. I'm resetting newstate so that it is easier to use, but state should still contain entries different from zeroes.

Comment: @BorisVerwoerd Not after you assign `newstate` to `state`.

Comment: Sorry I lost you here. If I read it correct, `newstate` is being set to 0, then given values by `state`. Then `state` is set equal to `newstate`, now they still have entries different from zero. But now when I said `newstate` to 0 again, `state` differs aswell, but why? I didn't equal them when `newstate` is still 0.

Comment: You copied the reference, so `newstate` and `state` are the same object.

Comment: Ah DAMN, I get it now. Completely forgot I was working with objects and that those things can happen. Thank you so much for helping me!